# .htaccess not recognizing https is on

Tags: .htaccess

I am getting a redirect error: `Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.` I have the following inside my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/test/ [L,R]
```

when I load `http://www.mysite.com` or `https://www.mysite.com` I get redirected to:

`https://www.mysite.com/test//test//test//test//test//test/......`

It appears that the `RewriteCond` does not recognize https as being on and continually loads that rewrite rule.

Why would this condition not fail when https is set?

Comment: Check your logs and make sure there isn't another step happening somewhere (like getting redirected back to non-HTTPS) in the middle

Comment: What happens if u change it like this: `RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/test/? [L,R]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following seemed to fix my problem:

`RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on [NC]`